# Change class based component to function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having trouble to convert a class based component, using Redux to use function and hooks.
I'm getting

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

This is my actual code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 

function App() {
  const { newValue } = this.props;
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ paddingTop: '10px' }}>
      <input type="text" />
      <button>Click me!</button>
      <h1>{newValue}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  newValue: store.clickState.newValue
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

If i change `function App()` to `class App extends Component` and put my `const { newValue } = this.props;` inside `render()` method, it works just fine. But with `function App()` only i still getting errros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function components receive props as a regular argument.

```
             
function App(props) {
  const { newValue } = props;
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ paddingTop: '10px' }}>
      <input type="text" />
      <button>Click me!</button>
      <h1>{newValue}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or better, normally you would destructure the props to let the users know how the `props` is "shaped".

```
function App({newValue}) {
...  
}
```

meaning, the users of the component would know (just by looking at the function declaration) what props are accepted by the component.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `this` in the functional component for props.

```
const { newValue } = this.props;
```

Should be

```
function App(props) {
  const { newValue } = props;
```